# transition a circle into a line by unrolling it with SVG and d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

For a project we are trying to make a circle into a line (and back again) while it is rotating along a linear path, much like a tire rotates and translates when rolling on a road, or a curled fore finger is extended and recurled into the palm.

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/cHXZZ/), I have a static SVG (the top circle) that rotates along the linear black path (which is above the circle, to mimic a finger extending) that is defined in the HTML.

I also use d3 to generate a "circle" that is made up of connected points (and can unfurl if you click on/in the circle thanks to @ChrisJamesC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120949/transition-between-a-circle-and-a-line-with-d3) ), and is translated and rotated
in the function moveAlongLine when you click on the purple Line:

```
function moveAlongLine() {
  circle.data([lineData])
  .attr("transform", "translate(78.5,0) rotate(-90, 257.08 70) ")
  .duration(1000)
  circle.on("click", transitionToCircle)
}
```

The first problem is that the `.duration(1000)` is not recognized and throws a `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'duration'` in the console, so there is a difference between the static definition of `dur` in SVG and dynamically setting it in JS/D3, but this is minor.

The other is should the transform attributes be abstracted from one another like in the static circle?   in the static circle, the translate is one animation, and the rotation is another, they just have the same star and duration, so they animate together.   How would you apply both in d3?

The challenge that I can not get, is how to let it unroll upwards(and also re-roll back), with the static point being the top center of the circle also being the same as the leftmost point on the line.

these seem better:

- I should try to get the unfurl animation to occur while also rotating? This seems like it would need to be stepwise/sequential based...
- Or Consider an octogon (defined as a path), and if it were to rotate 7 of the sides, then 6, then 5....   Do this for a rather large number of points on a polyhedron? (the circle only needs to be around 50 or so pixels, so 100 points would be more than enough) This is the middle example in the fiddle.   Maybe doing this programmatically?
- Or This makes me think of a different way:   (in the case of the octogon), I could have 8 line paths (with no Z, just an additional closing point), and transition between them?   Like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/PafRU/)
- Or anything todo with keyframes?   I have made an animation in Synfig, but am unsure ho get it to SVG.  The synfig file is at http://specialorange.org/filedrop/unroll.sifz if you can convert to SVG, but the xsl file [here](http://linkmauve.fr/dev/synfig/sif2svg/) doesn't correctly convert it for me using `xsltproc`.

this seems really complicated but potential:

- Define a path (likely a bézier curve with the same number of reference points) that the points follow, and have the reference points dynamically translate as well...  see [this](http://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/) for an concept example

this seems complicated and clunky:

- Make a real circle roll by, with a growing mask in front of it, all while a line grows in length

A couple of notes:

- The number of points in the d3 circle can be adjusted in the JS, it is currently set low so that you can see a bit of a point in the rendering to verify the rotation has occurred (much like the gradient is in the top circle).
- this is to help students learn what is conserved between a number line and a circle, specifically to help learn fractions.  For concept application, take a look at [compthink.cs.vt.edu:3000](http://compthink.cs.vt.edu:3000) to see our prototype, and this will help with switching representations, to help you get a better idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the same function that generates the circle as in the question, and did a bit of thinking, and it seemed like I wanted an animation that looked like a finger unrolling like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/PafRU/).  This lead me to the math and idea needed to make it happen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/6sYAY/).

The answer is an array of arrays, with each nested array being a line in the different state, and then animate by interpolating between the points.

```
var circleStates = [];
for (i=0; i<totalPoints; i++){
    //circle portion
    var circleState = $.map(Array(numberOfPoints), function (d, j) {
      var x = marginleft + radius + lineDivision*i + radius * Math.sin(2 * j * Math.PI / (numberOfPoints - 1));
      var y =  margintop + radius - radius * Math.cos(2 * j * Math.PI / (numberOfPoints - 1));
      return { x: x, y: y};
    })
    circleState.splice(numberOfPoints-i);
    //line portion
    var lineState = $.map(Array(numberOfPoints), function (d, j) {
      var x = marginleft + radius + lineDivision*j;
      var y =  margintop;
      return { x: x, y: y};
    })
    lineState.splice(i);
    //together
    var individualState = lineState.concat(circleState);
    circleStates.push(individualState);
}
```

and the animation(s)

```
function all() {
    for(i=0; i<numberOfPoints; i++){
      circle.data([circleStates[i]])
        .transition()
        .delay(dur*i)
        .duration(dur)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr('d', pathFunction)            
    }
}
function reverse() {
    for(i=0; i<numberOfPoints; i++){
      circle.data([circleStates[numberOfPoints-1-i]])
        .transition()
        .delay(dur*i)
        .duration(dur)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr('d', pathFunction)            
     }
}
```

Comment: That's nice! I think you can also use always the same array with some push-pop-map functions but it might make things harder to understand and slower than what you actually do. (ChrisJamecC)

Answer (score 0):

(Note: This should be in comments but not enough spacing)

1. **Circle Animation**
   Try the [radial wipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591614/svg-radial-wipe-animation-using-css3-js) from SO. Need to tweak it so angle starts at 180 and ends back at same place (line#4-6,19) and move along the X-axis (line#11) on each interation. Change the `<path...` attribute to suit your taste.

**Line Animation** Grow a line from single point to the length (perimeter) of the circle.

Sync both animation so that it appears good on all browsers (major headache!).

Comment: Update: For 1., you can wrap the path with `<g transform="translate(200,200) rotate(180)">`. So all you need is add offset to x-axis in line #11 that matches the x-values in 2.

Comment: So you are saying have a mask that rotates along with a circle?   we have the benefit of only having to develop for chrome since it is the only browser who supports the web-audio kit